# Is there a way to simply do a select on multiple tables with the query builder?

Tags: laravel

I would like to get results from 2 tables ordered by creation date.

Is there a way to make it with the Laravel query builder and then get a Collection ?

It seems so basic but I can't find how to achieve that.

Thanks in advance for any help.

```
$articles = DB::table(['news', 'posts'])->orderBy('created_at')->get();
```

Comment: What would the output of this query look like? Do both tables have the same columns?

Comment: Yes, it they have the same column (or I could only select the same)

Comment: Whats the relation for the news and posts and the primary foreign key. Please provide the column name.

Comment: Hello, actually there is no relation between the tables, no foreign keys, columns are just : ID (PRIMARY), TITLE, TEXT, CREATED_AT, UPDATED_AT. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get the collection of two tables in a single collection

but you can merge two collections into one.

```
$posts = DB::table('posts')->orderBy('created_at')->get();


$news = DB::table('news')->orderBy('created_at')->get();

$articles = $posts->merge($news);
```

Comment: Hi Adnan, thank you but the idea here is to have only one query for paginate, ordering facilities, etc.